# prepending the matched string in sed

Tags: sed

Starting with this input:

```
$ cat file1
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can put the fist set of numbers in parenthesis:

```
$ sed -En 's/[0-9]*:/(&)/ p'
Bus 001 Device (001:) ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device (001:) ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But if I also  try to prepend the line with & (the matched string) I get nothing:

```
$ sed -En 's/[0-9]*:/(&)/ ; s/^/(&)/ p' infile
()Bus 001 Device (001:) ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
()Bus 002 Device (001:) ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you match `^`, the matched string is empty. What exactly are you trying to prepend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` in the replacement part of the `s` command is a placeholder for whatever the regular expression matched *in the same `s` command*.

Your second substitution is `s/^/(&)/`, and since this would match the empty string at the start of any line, it would insert the literal string `()` at the beginning of each line.  The parenthesis would be empty since the `&` is replaced by an empty string.

If you want to match the first substring of digits (with a trailing `:`), put these into a parenthesis, and also prepend the parenthesis with the digits to the start of the line, then you would have to let the `s` command modify the relevant part of the line in one go, possibly like this:

```bash
$ sed 's/\(.*Device \)\([0-9]*:\)/(\2)\1(\2)/' file
(001:)Bus 001 Device (001:) ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
(001:)Bus 002 Device (001:) ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here, I've made sure to match and collect the part before the device number as well as the number and the colon in two capture groups.  I can then append and prepend the second group (in parentheses) to the first group in the replacement text.

I'm matching the initial part of the line with `.*Device`  because if I had used just `.*`, it would have gobbled up the digits preceding the `:` as well, and the second group would only have contained the colon.

Alternatively, with two substitutions where the first substitution puts the number and colon in a parenthesis and the second one matches the parenthesis and prepends it to the line:

```bash
$ sed -e 's/[0-9]*:/(&)/' -e 's/\(.*\)\((.*)\)/\2\1\2/' file
(001:)Bus 001 Device (001:) ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
(001:)Bus 002 Device (001:) ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

In short: The `s` command can only modify the part of the string that is matched by the regular expression, and the `&` placeholder is replaced by the text that is matched by the regular expression in the current `s` command. If you need to duplicate and/or modify something in the middle of the text *and* move it to the start of the line, then you have to match all those parts of the string, possibly capturing them in capture groups.

Comment: I didn't know about this limitations of &. Thank you for explaining.